# How to simulate an octomap file (.ot) in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:

I have a map defined by an Octomap file (.ot extension) wich I can visualize properly in rviz using octomap_server. However, I couldn't find an easy way to import this map into gazebo in order to simulate collisions and camera vision.
So far, I have tried to write some code which creates a .world file from the occupied cells, but after trying to load it in Gazebo it seems to freeze the simulator at the beginning and the general performance is awful.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219759/how-to-simulate-an-octomap-file-(.ot)-in-gazebo?/) by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Old question, but it came up in Google for me, so here it is-- an octomap is data structure for representing information about the environment. Gazebo is meant more as a physics simulator. For example, moving robots around a room with rigid obstacles such as a couch, table, and walls. The robot and obstacles are visualized as themselves, and they have configuration-file-defined physical properties. Some additional visualizations do exist, such as sensor field of view, but I see those as "extras". RViz, on the other hand, does not use a physics engine, and only displays data collected (in our case) from ROS topics. And that data has already been converted to some ROS/RViz-compliant representation, whether that's a point cloud, marker array, coordinate frame, etc.

tl;dr Gazebo is used for physical simulation, while RViz is used for data visualization. You'd likely use both at the same time in many instances. See [this page](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) for some examples.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0